# Swift Mailer long delay

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I have a strange issue with swiftmailer. When I try to send an email the page load takes up to 3 minutes and there is no email sent.
Here is the code I use:

```
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject("test")
->setTo(array('foo@bar.com' => "testasdsadasd"))
->setFrom(array('asdasd@dsfsf.com' => 'asdasd@sdfsf.com'))
->setBody($body, 'text/html');
$mailer->send($message);
```

And here is the code I use when I try to debug. The result of var_dump is array(0) { }

```
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
$body = "Test";
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
->setSubject("test")
->setTo(array('foo@bar.com' => "testasdsadasd"))
->setFrom(array('asdasd@dsfsf.com' => 'asdasd@sdfsf.com'))
->setBody($body, 'text/html');
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
#$mailer->send($message);

$logger = new Swift_Plugins_Loggers_EchoLogger();
$mailer->registerPlugin(new Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin($logger));

$result = $mailer->send($message, $failures);
var_dump($failures);
```

Answer (score 0):

is your configuration of SwiftMailer ok ? 
Which transporter do you use? 
If you use sendmail, you have to add a line in the file `/etc/hosts`
it should look like this : `127.0.0.1        localhost             localhost.localdomain`